# arcpy.da.SearchCursor is skipping rows when selection is "large"

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

In ArcMap 10.6.1 I have a script Python (2.7.14) in a simple ArcToolbox that uses an arcpy.da.SearchCursor to iterate through the selected point features (poles) to produce an Excel report. The cursor calls a function that does the job of producing the report.

There is a Boolean in the parameters (inclPService) In  that indicates that for that pole I will not produce the report.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(SelectedLayer, ("CODE", "COMPLETE", "SIDE1", "SIDE2", "DAMAGE", "ANCHOR1", "ANCHOR2", "ANCHOR3", "ANCHOR4")) as rows:   # nuevas fotos
    for row in rows:
        nrPoles += 1
        CODE = row[0].upper()
        arcpy.AddMessage("Appel CODE " + CODE)
        createExcel_fromSQLite.WriteLog("Appel CODE: " + CODE, LogFilePath)            
        for i in range(1,9): 
            picPole = traitemPhotos(i,row[i])
            picPoleBaseName = os.path.basename(picPole)              
            if picPoleBaseName  is None or picPoleBaseName  == "":
                continue
            else:
                listPics.append(picPole)

        # CALL TO MAIN PROCESSUS MODULE:
        result = createExcel_fromSQLite.mainProcessus(CODE, excelFolder, sqlitePath, listPics, Logo1, Logo2, paperSize, LogFilePath, distTolerance, inclPService)
        #arcpy.AddMessage("Nr photos " + str(len(listPics)))
        listPics[:] = []
arcpy.AddMessage("Nr poles :" + str(nrPoles))
```

The code works perfectly when I select certain number of features, say 10, 20. It lists the code of the pole and logs about the processes and queries inside the function, as expected.

However, when I select much more, say, 120, the code simply ignores the relevant features and gives me the code of the poles that should not be processed (correctly) but ignoring totally the poles that should be processed.

It is not like I have selected other features because I have tested selecting a subset of the poles that I have previously selected.

I can not understand that behaviour.

Am I missing something about the da.SearchCursor?

Comment: If you have a Boolean, you should be using it in a `sql_clause` parameter (and the column should be indexed).  The source layer will honor the selection set, but only if you pass in a `Layer` and not a source (in which case it will generate a "Miranda" layer, with all features selected)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/450851/edit) to include a screenshot of the toolbox tool parameter settings, code that shows how you access and use those parameters and what you mean by "select" (do you manually select features before running the tool or are you selecting in code).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, yesterday I was doing other things at work. Today I did a new tests and I included the boolean as in the sql_clause and it did work. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the delay. Since the question was closed I can not vote that Vince gave me the correct answer.